# array push function adds one more empty index into array

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, push

```
function spacing(num){
    var a=[];
    var aToStr="";
    for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
        a.push("&nbsp")
    }
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        aToStr=a[i]+aToStr;
    }
    // alert(a.length);result is 5 here
    // alert(aToStr.split("&").length);//here result is 6 and when printed to screen theres an empty index
    return aToStr;
}
```

As I explained in the code.Something is happening in array and somehow 1 more index appears.
When I print it to screen theres just a white-space in that index.

Comment: If you have "x-x-x" you have 2 separators, but 3 x's. There is an expected behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

> When found, separator is removed from the string and the substrings are returned in an array.

### Explanation of error:

1. Start searching with `split`, find first &

   ```
   &nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   // & found and removed, resulting in  ' '
   // returnArrForSplit = ['']
   ```
2. Find second &

   ```
   nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   // & found and removed, everything before pushed to returnArrForSplit, 'nbsp'
   // returnArrForSplit = ['', nbsp]
   ```
3. Third &

   ```
   nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   // & found and removed, resulting in  'nbsp'
   // returnArrForSplit = ['', nbsp, nbsp]
   ```
4. Fourth &

   ```
   nbsp&nbsp&nbsp
   // & found and removed, resulting in  'nbsp'
   // returnArrForSplit = ['', nbsp, nbsp, nbsp]
   ```
5. Final &

   ```
   nbsp&nbsp
   // & found and removed, resulting in  'nbsp'
   // returnArrForSplit = ['', nbsp, nbsp, nbsp, nbsp]
   ```
6. But there is still one `nbsp` left!

   ```
   nbsp
   // added as last substring
   // returnArrForSplit = ['', nbsp, nbsp, nbsp, nbsp, nbsp]
   returnArrForSplit.shift()
   // removes unwanted empty string.
   ```

### Fixed Code

```
function spacing(num){
    var a=[];
    var aToStr="";
    for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
        a.push("&nbsp")
    }
    for(i=0;i<a.length;i++) {
        aToStr=a[i]+aToStr;
    }

    return aToStr;
}

var spaces = spacing(5);
// "&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"

spaces = spaces.split('&');
// ["", "nbsp", "nbsp", "nbsp", "nbsp", "nbsp"]

spaces.shift() // returns ''
// spaces is ["nbsp", "nbsp", "nbsp", "nbsp", "nbsp"]
```

Comment: `aToStr` is a string, not an array, so you can't `shift` it

Comment: when i set a.push("&nbsp ") with one white-space,and split by whitespaces anyway it returns one more index

Comment: ah yes i understood now it adds into the end coz it is &nbsp+whitespace in the end as well thank u for helping

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your question should be simplified to:

*Why*

```
"&nbsp&nbsp".split("&").length
```

*is 3 instead of 2 ?*

**or**

*Why*

```
"&".split("&").length
```

*is 2 instead of 0 ?*

For the last version the answer is that JavaScript considers that you have 2 **empty string**s ( `""` ): one of them before the separator, and one of them after it. Why? This is how they decided to implement this function => **just a decision**. In Java, a similar attempt will return `0`.

If you think that this is strange, notice that `"a".split("b").length` returns `1` !

So, JavaScript considers that `answer = 1 + numberOfAppearancesForThatSeparator`.